# Pass by value or const reference to function?

Tags: c++, set, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Should I pass `std::string` by value or by reference to one function. This function store this values in member variable of class.

I am always confuse when about pass by value or reference. Please clear my confusion about this.

Here is code :

```
class DataStore {
public:
    void addFile(const string& filename, const set< std::string>& filePaths)
    {  
        if (dataStoreMap.insert(make_pair(filename, filePaths)).second)
        {
            cout << "Data Added" <<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Data not Added" << endl;
        }
    }
private:
    // member variable
    map < string, set < string >  > dataStoreMap;
};
```

Shall I make function declaration like this :

```
void addFile(const string& filename, const set< std::string>& filePaths)
```

or

```
void addFile(const string filename, const set< std::string> filePaths)
```

Both gives same result. If there any issue about memory allocation or performance.

Above function call from `cpp` class.

```
DataStore ds;
set<string> setFileDirectory{ "1", "2", "3", "4", "6", "5" };
ds.addFile("file.txt", setFileDirectory);

setFileDirectory.erase(setFileDirectory.begin(), setFileDirectory.end());
setFileDirectory.insert({ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" });
ds.addFile("demo.txt", setFileDirectory);
```

Any detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I understand what you mean but when i have to use value or ref. that is still confusing for me. Here i am going to store values in map so pass by value is good thing? or Pass by ref?

Comment: Is your question what the difference between passing by value and passing by reference is?

Comment: @Namfuak : Confusion between when to use pass by ref or pass by value.

Answer (score 3):

When you have an **input** parameter, i.e. something that is *observed* by the function and *not* modified, consider passing it by **const reference** (`const &`), to avoid useless deep-copies (which may require dynamic memory allocations, etc.)

```
void addFile(const std::string& filename, 
             const std::set<std::string>& filePaths)
```

---

**P.S.**
Of course, if you are passing parameters that are *cheap to copy*, like `int`s, you can just pass by value :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I understand what you mean but when i have to use value or ref. that is still confusing for me. Here i am going to store values in map so pass by value is good thing? or Pass by ref?

Comment: @Sam_k: Please keep two aspects distinct: what you store in the map (or other containers), and what you pass to the function as parameters. My answer focuses on what to pass as parameters, and I won't repeat my answer in this comment. Instead, about storing stuff in containers, in general storing values is a good choice: it makes deep-copies of the values, so they are "physically" contained in the container, and decoupled from other external contexts (this also simplifies ownership, lifetime management, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If your container set has a huge size and passing string to function is comparatively small I may use as follows:

```
void addFile(const string filename, const set< std::string> & filePaths)
```

Comment: [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) returns a `pair<iterator, bool>`, the second element being true if the insertion was successful and false if not, which seems like what he intended to check.  Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Its right. I am checking true or false which is return by insert function

Answer (score 0):

The first has "better" performance, because the second makes a copy of the `string` before passing it.  Since you aren't modifying the `string`, there is no downside passing a reference to the actual string in the calling function rather than making a copy, and takes less memory to copy a reference than a `string`.  That said, the compiler may end up treating them equivalently if you never cast off the const specifier on the `string` variable.  This difference is more useful on large parameters, for example if your `filepaths` variable had a few thousand elements there may be a very noticeable difference in passing it by reference rather than by value.

Related: [Is it better in C++ to pass by value or pass by constant reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/is-it-better-in-c-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-constant-reference?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should *never* pass arguments by **`const` value** as there's hardly any reason for it. Passing by value already makes sure you can not alter the variable at the call site as it is *copied*.

Now, the question still remains about passing arguments by value or reference. And the answer is more complicated than could be expected. There are a lot of good answers written about this on Stack Overflow.

In short, when passing potentially large objects (like `std::vector` or `std::string`) to functions use these idiomatic guidelines:

- When passing for observation (read only) pass by reference to `const`.
- When passing an argument that you want to retain a copy of (so called *sink argument*), then also pass by reference to `const`. If the passed object is movable you can also add an overload taking the argument by *rvalue reference* (`T&&`) for optimization.

Related info:

- [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)
- [Is it better in C++ to pass by value or pass by constant reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/is-it-better-in-c-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-constant-reference)
- [Dave Abrahams - Want Speed? Pass by Value](https://web.archive.org/web/20100919084133/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)
- [What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics)
- [Why is value taking setter member functions not recommended in Herb Sutter's CppCon 2014 talk (Back to Basics: Modern C++ Style)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261007/why-is-value-taking-setter-member-functions-not-recommended-in-herb-sutters-cpp)

Comment: "here's hardly any reason for it (except for built-in types)" What's the exception for built-in types?

Comment: @NeilKirk Well IMO sometimes it can be practical to use e.g. `const int` for a number you don't want modified inside the function (it only adds value to the implementer). Still I removed that part as my argument is a bit weak :)