# const or ref or const ref or value as an argument of setter function

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-passing

Constantness

```
class MyClass {
// ...
private:
    std::string m_parameter;
// ...
}
```

Pass-by-value:

```
void MyClass::SetParameter(std::string parameter)
{
    m_parameter = parameter;
}
```

Pass-by-ref:

```
void MyClass::SetParameter(std::string& parameter)
{
    m_parameter = parameter;
}
```

Pass-by-const-ref:

```
void MyClass::SetParameter(const std::string& parameter)
{
    m_parameter = parameter;
}
```

Pass-by-const-value:

```
void MyClass::SetParameter(const std::string parameter)
{
    m_parameter = parameter;
}
```

Pass-by-universal-ref:

```
void MyClass::SetParameter(std::string&& parameter)
{
    m_parameter = parameter;
}
```

Pass-by-const-universal-ref:

```
void MyClass::SetParameter(const std::string&& parameter)
{
    m_parameter = parameter;
}
```

Which variant is the best (possibly in terms of C++11 and its move semantics)?

PS. May be bodies of the functions is in some cases incorrect.

Comment: Your last two examples are not universal references, they are rvalue references.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31154012/ http://stackoverflow.com/q/21035417/ and many more

Comment: The answer may differ according to what are the semantics of the class and what you are trying to achieve.  If unsure/general case const ref is the best

Comment: @Andre What I am trying to achieve: it is a simple setter for private member. No matter what semantics is.

Answer (score 8):

1. Pass by value: not good in general as a value copy might be taken. (Although a move constructor might mitigate).
2. Pass by reference: not good as the function *might* modify the parameter passed. Also an anonymous temporary *cannot* bind to a reference.
3. Pass by `const` reference: still the best. No copy taken, function cannot modify the parameter, and an anonymous temporary can bind to a `const` reference.
4. Passing by `&&` variants: Currently pointless, as there are no move semantics given the way you've written the function bodies. If you'd written `std::move(m_parameter, parameter)` in place of the assignment then this might win over (3) in some cases, and the compiler will pick the better.

Comment: 3. When passing by const reference, there IS copy of value from where ref is pointed to. And calling `SetParameter("blahblahblah")` makes temporary, which is copied then.

Comment: I disagree that pass by value is not good in this case. There's going to be a copy anyway, so making it in the interface then calling `std::move` on it may be more efficient than the const reference version.

Comment: @TartanLlama Both pass-by-value and pass-by-const-ref have cases where they're (theoretically) more efficient than the other one.

Comment: @dyp yeah, that's why I said "may be". I was just disagreeing that pass-by-value is not good rather than arguing that it's the best option :)

Answer (score 1):

See 'Effective C++' Scott Meyers - If the private member is a built in type then it can be more efficient to pass by value than pass by reference (which are typically implemented as pointers in the compiler). This is also true for iterators and function objects in STL which are designed to be passed by value. Otherwise pass by reference-to-const is preferable.