# move or copy when passing arguments to the constructor and member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics, stdmove

The following is an example of my typical code. A have a lot of objects that look like this:

```
struct Config
{
    Config();
    Config(const std::string& cType, const std::string& nType); //additional variables omitted
    Config(Config&&) = default;
    Config& operator=(Config&&) = default;

    bool operator==(const Config& c) const;
    bool operator!=(const Config& c) const;

    void doSomething(const std::string& str);
    bool doAnotherThing(const MyOtherObject& obj);
    void doYetAnotherThing(int value1, unsigned long value2, const std::string& value3, MyEnums::Seasons value4, const std::vector<MySecondObject>& value5);

    std::string m_controllerType;
    std::string m_networkType;
    //...
};

//...

Config::Config(const std::string& cType, const std::string& nType) :
    m_controllerType(cType),
    m_networkType(nType)
{
}
```

My motivations and general understand of the subject:

- use const references in constructors and methods to avoid double-copying when passing objects.
- simple types - pass by value; classes and structs - pass by const reference (or simple reference when I need to modify them)
- force compiler to create `default` move constructor and move assignment so that It would be able to do it's fancy magic and simultaneously it allows to avoid writing boring `ctor() : m_v1(std::move(v1)), m_v2(std::move(v2)), m_v3(std::move(v3)) {}`.
- if it performs badly, use libc and raw pointers, then wrap it at class and write a comment.

I have a strong feeling that by rules of thumb are flawed and simply incorrect.

After reading cppreference, Scott Mayers, C++ standard, Stroustrup and so on, I feel like: "Yea, I understand every word here, but it still doesn't make any sense'. The only thing I king of understood is that move semantics makes sense when my class contains non-copiable types, like `std::mutex` and `std::unique_ptr`.

I've seen a lot of code where people pass complex object by value, like large strings, vectors and custom classes - I believe this is where move semantics happen, but, again, how can you pass an object to a function by move? If I am correct, it would leave an object in a "kind-of-null-state", making it unusable.

So, the questionы are: 
- How do I correctly decide between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference?
- Do I need to provide both copy and move constructors? 
- Do I need to explicitly write move and copy constructors? May I use `= default`? My classes are mostly POD object so there is no complex login involved.
- When debugging, I can always write `std::cout << "move\n";` or `std::cout << "copy\n";` in constructors of my own classes, but how do I know what happens with classes from `stdlib`?

P.S. It may look like it is a cry out of desperation (it is), not a valid SO question. I simply don't know to formulate my problems better than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If it is a primitive type, pass by value.  Locality of reference wins.
- If you aren't going to store a copy of it, pass by value or `const&`.
- If you want to store a copy of it, and it is very cheap to move and modestly expensive to copy, pass by *value*.
- If something has a modest cost to move, and is a sink parameter, consider pass by rvalue reference.  Users will be forced to `std::move`.
- Consider providing a way for callers to emplace construct into the field in highly generic code, or where you need every ounce of performance

[The Rule of 0/3/5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) describes how you should handle copy assign/construct/destroy.  Ideally you follow the rule of 0; copy/move/destruct is all `=default` in anything except resource management types.  If you want to implement *any* of copy/move/destruct, you need to implement, `=default` or `=delete` every other one of the 5.

If you are only taking 1 argument to a setter, consider writing both the `&&` and `const&` versions of the setter.  Or just exposing the underlying object.  Move-assignment sometimes reuses storage and that is efficient.

Emplacing looks like this:

```
struct emplace_tag {};
struct wrap_foo {
  template<class...Ts>
  wrap_foo(emplace_tag, Ts&&...ts):
    foo( std::forward<Ts>(ts)... )
  {}
  template<class T0, class...Ts>
  wrap_foo(emplace_tag, std::initializer_list<T0> il, Ts&&...ts):
    foo( il, std::forward<Ts>(ts)... )
  {}
private:
  Foo foo;
};
```

there are a myriad of other ways you can permit "emplace" construction.  See `emplace_back` or `emplace` in standard containers as well (where they use placement `::new` to construct objects, forwarding objects passed in).

Emplace construct even permits direct construction without even a move using objects with an `operator T()` setup properly.  But that is something that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I have read that "take by value and move when you want a copy" is not necessarily the best option. [Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261007/why-is-value-taking-setter-member-functions-not-recommended-in-herb-sutters-cpp). But overall this is solid advice.

Comment: @MaxLanghof That link is for setters, not constructors.  There is no preexisting storage for constructors.  Which is mostly what I'm talking about above (note I say that assignment should almost always be just =defaulted).

Comment: "Consider providing a way for callers to emplace construct into the field in highly generic code, or where you need every ounce of performance" May you explain it a bit more? With an example, if possible.

Comment: @MaxLanghof But this question goes beyond construction, so I've addressed it now.