# Pass-by-value and std::move vs forwarding reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-value, forwarding-reference, pass-by-const-reference, pass-by-rvalue-reference

I encounter the pass by value and move idiom quite often:

```
struct Test
{
    Test(std::string str_) : str{std::move(str_)} {}
    std::string str;
};
```

But it seems to me that passing by either const reference or rvalue reference can save a copy in some situations.  Something like:

```
struct Test1
{
    Test1(std::string&& str_) : str{std::move(str_)} {}
    Test1(std::string const& str_) : str{str_} {}
    std::string str;
};
```

Or maybe using a forwarding reference to avoid writing both constructors.  Something like:

```
struct Test2
{
    template<typename T> Test2(T&& str_) : str{std::forward<T>(str_)} {}
    std::string str;
};
```

Is this the case?  And if so, why is it not used instead?

Additionally, it looks like C++20 allows the use of auto parameters to simplify the syntax.  I am not sure what the syntax would be in this case.  Consider:

```
struct Test3
{
    Test3(auto&& str_) : str{std::forward<decltype(str_)>(str_)} {}
    std::string str;
};

struct Test4
{
    Test4(auto str_) : str{std::forward<decltype(str_)>(str_)} {}
    std::string str;
};
```

**Edit:**

The suggested questions are informative, but they do not mention the "auto" case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the pass-by-value-and-then-move construct a bad idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035417/is-the-pass-by-value-and-then-move-construct-a-bad-idiom)

Comment: This is analyzed in detail in "Modern C++" textbook by Scott Meyers.

Comment: @康桓瑋 No, it is a different question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it seems to me that passing by either const reference or rvalue reference can save a copy in some situations.

Indeed, but it requires more overloads (and even worst with several parameters).

Pass by value and move idiom has (at worst) one extra move. which is a good trade-off most of the time.

> maybe using a forwarding reference to avoid writing both constructors.

Forwarding reference has its own pitfalls:

- disallows `{..}` syntax for parameter as `{..}` has no type.

  ```
  Test2 a({5u, '*'}); // "*****"
  ```

  would not be possible.
- is not restrict to valid types (requires extra `requires` or SFINAE).

  ```
  Test2 b(4.2f); // Invalid, but `std::is_constructible_v<Test2, float>` is (falsely) true.
  ```

  would produces error inside the constructor, and not at call site (so error message less clear, and SFINAE not possible).
- for constructor, it can take precedence over copy constructor (for non-const l-value)

  ```
  Test2 c(a); // Call Test2(T&&) with T=Test2&
              // instead of copy constructor Test2(const Test2&)
  ```

  would produce error, as `std::string` cannot be constructed from `Test2&`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the pitfalls in less technical terms?

Comment: Also, there should not be overloads with a template (or auto) syntax

Comment: Some examples added. I hope it is clearer.

Comment: Any comments about Test3/Test4?

Comment: `Test3` is syntaxic sugar for `Test2`. Test4 is for `template <typename T> Test4(T str);`, which takes argument by value. only advantage from `Test3` is that copying a non-const l-value of `Test4` would be ambiguous instead of hard error (so "better" error message).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69742634/4944425) by [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539) and the proposed dupes<sup>(1)</sup>, you can overcome the shown pitfalls of the forward reference approach by restricting the valid types of a template parameter pack.

```c++
#include <string>
#include <concepts>

struct Test
{
    template<class... Args>
        requires std::constructible_from<std::string, Args...>
    Test(Args&&... str_)
        : str( std::forward<Args>(str_)... )
    {}
    std::string str;
};

int main()
{
    Test a{"So far, so good..."};

    Test b{5u, '*'};      // -> "*****"

//    Test b({5u, '*'});  // It works too.
    
    Test c{b};

//    Test d(4.2f);
// error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Test'
}
```

---

(1) [Is the pass-by-value-and-then-move construct a bad idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035417/is-the-pass-by-value-and-then-move-construct-a-bad-idiom) and
[Advantages of pass-by-value and std::move over pass-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705967/advantages-of-pass-by-value-and-stdmove-over-pass-by-reference)