# Is there any point in returning an object (e.g., std::string) by reference when the method has no parameters?

Tags: c++

Take the following snippet of code

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
  
 class Foo {
 private:
     std::string m_name;
     
 public:
     Foo(std::string name) : m_name { name } {}
     const std::string & get_name() const { return m_name; } 
 };
 
 int main() {
     Foo x { "bob" };
     x.get_name();
 }
```

Because I initialized an object and `name` exists somewhere in memory, is a temporary object is made when I call the `x.get_name()`? If a temporary object is made, than is there a point to returning by reference? My understanding is you return by reference so to avoid the cost of creating a large object or when using an `std::ostream&` object because you have to.

Comment: The function returns a reference to the existing `name`, no temporary is created.

Comment: side note on naming: avoid having member variables and parameter (e.g in ctor) with same name, it's just a shortcut to problems and headaches. Pick a convention, e.g. trailing unserscore for member variable `name_` Compiler has no problem handling names an scopes. Human can have. To me, `: name { name } `is something I have to think about for a while. "Oh yes, it's using the `name` parameter value to initialize `name` member variable"; and it get much worse when you have long methods. "this `name` is the member variable, ain't it? oh no, it's the parameter of this method`

Comment: the returned value is ignored. The line `x.get_name();` does nothing

Comment: Adding to what Gian said: What would `Foo(std::string name) : foo{name}, name{name}, bla{name} { blub = name; }` do? Which `name` is used in each case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a point, you return by reference if you want to return a reference to some object.

Why would you want to have a reference to some object? Exactly because you need to access *it* and not a copy of *it*. Reasons might vary, basic ones are that you do not want to make an extra copy - e.g. the `get_name` you posted, maybe you want to store it and access it later, and/or because you want to modify it.

Returning a reference is not much different from a passing parameter by reference.

No temporary `std::string` object is made in `x.get_name()`. The method returns lvalue reference by value. Since references are usually implemented as pointers, the true return value is a pointer. So a copy of the pointer is made during each call but that is like returning an `int` - can be done in registers or stack. So it's as cheap as it gets.

Yes, your understanding is correct, although I would say that `const T&` is used when we want to avoid copy for whatever reasons and `T&` should only be used when we need to get mutable access to the object - e.g. `std::ostream&` in `operator<<` which mutates the stream by printing into it.

BTW, you make an extra copy in your ctor - `name` parameter is copied into `name` member. Instead you should [move it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705967/advantages-of-pass-by-value-and-stdmove-over-pass-by-reference) there like `Foo(std::string name):name(std::move(name)){}`.

Comment: Getting the string by reference and then copying it to name member variable would be more efficient. Only a copy. Your approach is a copy to parameter of the constructor and then a move to name member.

Comment: @digito_evo Yes, but how do you get it by reference? `const std::string&`? Doesn't work for string literals as is in OP's example. `std::string_view` might be best here though.

Comment: `const std::string&` definitely works for string literals. Because it can bind to an rvalue of the same type. Just go try it in [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/e6777r76T) and see it for yourself. And yes, the `string_view` version generates a smaller and more efficient code.

Comment: @digito_evo No it does not, compiler can just optimize short strings to elide the construction of `std::string` for inlined functions. [See for yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/5E4TY8jdc) in case of longer strings, there is `new` present because `std::string` must be created from the string literal.

Comment: Oh right. Pass by reference does two allocations. Pass by value does a single allocation.