# Does C++ moves by default an string in a ctor?

Tags: c++, string, move

Given this example:

```
#include <string>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(std::string p_member) : m_member{p_member} {}
private:
    std::string m_member;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f{"Test"};
    
    return 0;
}
```

In `Foo` ctor, is the string copied or moved by default? Do I have to explicitly write the `std::move(p_member)`?

Comment: Pedantically, it is copied. If the C++ compiler can prove that there are no observable effects (I'd give it 50-50 odds), it can optimize it to a move. If you want to guarantee a move, yes, make it explicit.

Comment: write code to be explicit, if you want it to be moved use `std::move`

Comment: As a side note, be careful with this kind of micro-optimizations. If you write `m_member{std::move(p_member)}` and half a year later you/someone_else add more logic to the constructor, where you would like to reuse your `p_member`, you will run into not so obvious bug.

Comment: [Dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929800/is-stdmove-really-needed-on-initialization-list-of-constructor-for-heavy-membe), [Dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705967/advantages-of-pass-by-value-and-stdmove-over-pass-by-reference)