# How do I use lambda with temporary object implementing move semantics?

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

I am trying to write a lambda that receives a temporary object.
The lambda will be cached for later execution, and will be executed after the original object was destructed (hence should make a copy if it).

Main points:

1. Define class `X` that implements move semantics, but disable copy-c'tor and assignment op,
2. Define function `foo(X x)` that receives this type,
3. Create lambda `l`, and store it general function-pointer type `std::function<void()>`, for later execution. We will call this function-pointer `f`,
4. After original `x` was destructed, execute `f`.

I did not manage to write this lambda.
I know I can solve this easily using *pointer to object* instead of *object*, but I want to learn whether it is possible to use the object directly, assuming I implemented all move semantics correctly.

Code example (which does not work correctly):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class X
{
private:
    std::string m_s;

public:
    X(){}

    X(X&& other)
    { m_s = std::move(other.m_s);}

    ~X()
    { m_s = "Object destructed...";}
    
    X& operator=(X&& other)
    { m_s = std::move(other.m_s); return *this;}

    void SetString(const char* s)
    { m_s = s;}
    
    void Print() const
    { ::printf("X::Print() - String value: '%s'\n", m_s.c_str());}

private:
    X(const X&) = delete;
    X& operator=(const X&) = delete;
};

void foo(X x)
{ x.Print();}

//  Predefined lambda:
auto l = [](X x){ foo(std::move(x));};

int main()
{
    std::function<void()> f = nullptr;

    //  Create temporary scope for 'x' to verify object 
    //  destruction happens before 'f' is called:
    {
        X x;
        x.SetString("Hello World!");

    
        f = [&](){ l(std::move(x));};
    }

    //  Expecting to see 'Hello World!'
    f();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"I could not find a way to compile this code without having various compilation errors..."* **What errors?** Always post complete error along with your question. In particular, right now there are errors related to accessibility of move constructor since it is `private`.

Comment: This is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Firstly `[=]` will try to copy your move-only object, you need `[x = std::move(x)]` to move it into the lambda. Secondly `std::function` requires the lambda to be copyable (yours isn't due to this capture), use `std::move_only_function` or `std::function_ref` instead.

Comment: The actual issue is probably that std::function requires it's callable type to be copy-constructible, so any lambda would also need to be copy-constructible, which in turn means all its members (captured variables) must also be.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've got my head around this now so I've rewritten my answer.  There's no way to make this work with `x` declared on the stack because how ever much moving you do, the parameter passed to `foo` will have been destroyed by the time the lambda actually executes.

Instead (and it's obvious, once you see it), `x` has to be dynamically allocated as this is the only way to manage its lifetime.  Given that observation, it becomes clear how to pass it around: there's a smart pointer for that, it's copyable (deliberately) and it's called `std::shared_ptr`.  So here's code that works correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

class X
{
    std::string m_s;

public:
    X () { }
    X (std::string s) { m_s = s; }
    ~X () { m_s = "destroyed"; std::cout << m_s << "\n"; }
    X (const X&) = delete;
    X& operator= (const X&) = delete;
    X (X&& other) { m_s = other.m_s; other.m_s.clear (); }
    X& operator= (X&& other) { m_s = other.m_s; other.m_s.clear (); return *this; };
    inline void Print() const { std::cout << m_s << "\n"; }
};

void foo (std::shared_ptr <X> x) { x->Print (); }

int main()
{
    std::function <void ()> f;

    {
        auto x = std::make_shared <X> ("Hello World!");
        f = [=] () { foo (x); };
    }

    f ();
}
```

Output:

> Hello World!
> destroyed

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/7O1MPE) (Wandbox appears to be broken :( )

And OP, if you post what you claim is a MRE, please:

- make sure it compiles
- include all the relevant `#include`s
- include all the relevant code (where are the [deleted] copy and [implemented] move constructors / operators?)

The first part of the question (which, on reflection, I agree you need to keep) should also be distilled down into a single code fragment.  Thank you.

Comment: Paul thank you for your answer but please note my question: "...Please keep in mind that 'x' on the stack will be destructed before 'foo()' is called...". In your answer you are using reference to 'x' on the stack. Your code will crash in real scenario, assuming timer thread can happen anytime.

Comment: That's not so.  A _copy_ of `x` is passed to `l`, with the contents of the original `x` moved into it, see (e.g.): https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706303/5743288

Comment: Paul, your example does not work. Read my question. Pay special attention to the section 'More debugging details' and test it accordingly: Put 'x' in its own scope and function 'f' in external scope and you will see that at best your example will give an empty string. At worth it will crash. Bottom line - I did thank you for your trouble but your answer does not work. Regarding 'minimal example' - my question is longer then minimal example. There is more then enough information in the question.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I've read your code more carefully now.  Quest could do with cleaning up though, only the latter part is necessary.  I will look into getting this to work and update my answer accordingly.

Comment: OK, fixed my answer (and added a rider); sorry I screwed up earlier and gave you a hard time when I in fact was the one in the wrong.  My ego, as ever, leave it at the door, Paul, deleted my stroppy comment.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I also re-wrote my question to contain a proper MRE. Your answer is working great. I am curious to know if it is possible without dynamic allocation, but as said your answer does solve the problem, so thanks again

Comment: Don't think so, accept the answer please (click on the tick mark). Thx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256846/discussion-between-pazo-and-paul-sanders).