# How to overload unary arithmetic with move semantic

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I would like to implement a unary arithmetic operator with move semantic for std::vector. The purpose is to avoid internal allocation inside the operator if it is applied on an rvalue.

The problem: the following operation does not compile: c = -(a + b)

The reason this does not compile is because the binary arithmetic operator + I implemented for std::vector returns a const lvalue (so that the compiler will complain on (a + b) = c, which doesn't make sense).

**The binary + operator**

```
template<class T, class AllocVect1, class AllocVect2>
inline const std::vector<T> operator+ (
    const std::vector<T, AllocVect1> &v1,
    const std::vector<T, AllocVect2> &v2) {
    std::vector<T> vout;

    *Compute vout = v1 + v2*

    return vout;
}
```

**The unary operator**

```
template<class T, class Alloc>
inline const std::vector<T>& operator- (std::vector<T, Alloc> &&v) {
    std::transform (
        v.begin (), 
        v.end (), 
        v.begin (), 
        [](const auto &val){return -val;});
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [MCVE].

Comment: Your proposed operator has confusing/surprising semantics. Why does it return a `const` reference?

Answer (score 0):

**Pass and return your vector by value.**

What may sound unintuitive, makes sense once you consider these things:

1. A temporary object can be implicitly *moved* into a value parameter -- no copy occurs. This is as if you would call `std::move` on a local variable.
2. This object (the parameter) can be modified in-place, since it has no `const` qualifier.
3. The modified object can be returned, and move semantics are again applied implicitly. You should never return references to local variables -- neither lvalue nor rvalue references.

```
template<class T>
std::vector<T> operator-(std::vector<T> v) { // 1.
    std::for_each( // 2.
        v.begin(), 
        v.end(), 
        [](T& val) {val = -val;});

    return v; // 3.
}
```

This operator can be called with both rvalues (move + modify + move) and lvalues (copy + modify + move).

This being said, there *are* advantages of separate overloads for `const Param&` and `Param&&`, the details of which are already explained in separate answers:

- [How true is "Want Speed? Pass by value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605579)
- [Why is value taking setter member functions not recommended in Herb Sutter's CppCon 2014 talk (Back to Basics: Modern C++ Style)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261007)

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation!

Comment: I do wonder however what will happen in the following assignment: auto c = -(a + b);? The operator+ returns a const lvalue so that programmers will not be tempted to write something like: (a + b) = 'some other vector'. But, since this operator+ returns a const lvalue, will it copy or move when calling the operator- you wrote in your answer?

Comment: `(a + b) = 'some other vector'` -- is this _really_ a use case worth protecting for? How often have you seen such code?

Comment: If you *also* fix `operator+` to return by value instead of const lvalue, everything will work -- you can't assign to an unnamed temp (so `(a + b) =`.. is disallowed), AND `-(a+b)` will "just work" without extra copies.

Comment: For primitive type (a+b) = 'something' issues the compiler error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment. If only there was something similar for general classes with defined overloads of the operator+