# Best C++ move constructor implementation practice

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-constructor

I am trying to understand the implementation of move-constructor.
We all know if we need to manage resources in a C++ class, we need to implement Rule of five (C++ programming).

Microsoft gives us an example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293665.aspx

Here is better one, which uses copy-swap to avoid code duplication:
[Dynamically allocating an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255612/dynamically-allocating-an-array-of-objects/255744#255744)

```
     // C++11
     A(A&& src) noexcept
         : mSize(0)
         , mArray(NULL)
     {
         // Can we write src.swap(*this);
         // or (*this).swap(src);
         (*this) = std::move(src); // Implements in terms of assignment
     }
```

In the move-constructor, directly:

```
         // Can we write src.swap(*this);
         // or (*this).swap(src);
```

Because I think `(*this) = std::move(src)` is a little more complicated. Because if we write as `(*this) = src` inadvertently, it would call normal assignment operator instead of the move-assignment-operator.

Apart from this question, in Microsoft's example, they wrote code like this: in move-assignment-operator, do we need to check self-assignment? Is it possible to happen?

```
// Move assignment operator.
MemoryBlock& operator=(MemoryBlock&& other)
{
   std::cout << "In operator=(MemoryBlock&&). length = " 
             << other._length << "." << std::endl;

   if (this != &other)
   {
      // Free the existing resource.
      delete[] _data;

      // Copy the data pointer and its length from the 
      // source object.
      _data = other._data;
      _length = other._length;

      // Release the data pointer from the source object so that
      // the destructor does not free the memory multiple times.
      other._data = nullptr;
      other._length = 0;
   }
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: The move constructor seems silly to me.  Why not just initialize everything in the initializer list and then set `src` to a valid moved from state?  That should be at most 4 assignments and 3 if you don't care about changing the size of the moved from object.

Comment: `In the move-constructor, directly: // Can we write src.swap(*this); // or (*this).swap(src);` I don't see why not, assuming you have a suitable `swap` method implemented.

Comment: Self-move-assignment can sometimes happen, specifically in sorting algorithms that do `swap(*it1, *it2)` it's possible that the two iterators could refer to the same element, which would do a self-swap, possibly leading to a self-move. If you've overloaded `swap(MemoryBlock&, MemoryBlock&)` then that shouldn't be a problem, a your specialized swap will be called instead of `std::swap`. Self-move should not happen otherwise, although it's still theoretically possible.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Interesting point, I have never checked if `this == &other` in assignment operators because I assumed that self assignment can only happen by mistake and that mistake should not be masked rather be discovered as soon as possible.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: I forgot to link to http://wg21.link/lwg2468

Comment: @NathanOliver, you are right. It is written in this way to avoid code duplication. It is easier to maintain.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik, thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is to implement the default constructor, copy constructor and `swap` function.

And then implement the move constructor, copy and move assignment operators using the first three.

E.g.:

```
struct X
{
    X();
    X(X const&);
    void swap(X&) noexcept;

    X(X&& b)
        : X() // delegate to the default constructor
    {
        b.swap(*this);
    }

    // Note that this operator implements both copy and move assignments.
    // It accepts its argument by value, which invokes the appropriate (copy or move) constructor.
    X& operator=(X b) {
        b.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

If you have been using this idiom in C++98, then once you add the move constructor you get the move assignment without writing a single line of code.

[In some cases this idiom may be not the most efficient](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/the-drawbacks-of-implementing-move.html). Because the copy operator always first constructs a temporary and then swaps with it. By hand coding the assignment operators it may be possible to get better performance. When in doubt, check optimized assembly output and use a profiler.

Answer (score 6):

I'm also looking over the Internet to find the best way to implement move constructor and move assignment. There are a few approaches but neither are perfect.

Following are my findings so far.

Here is a `Test` class I'm using as an example:

```cpp
class Test {
private:
  std::string name_;
  void*       handle_ = nullptr;

public:
  Test(std::string name)
    : name_(std::move(name))
    , handle_(malloc(128))
  {
  }
    
  ~Test()
  {
    if(handle_) free(handle_);
  } 

  Test(Test&& other) noexcept;             // we are going to implement it
  Test& operator=(Test&& other) noexcept;  // we are going to implement it

  void swap(Test& v) noexcept
  {
    std::swap(this->handle_, v.handle_);
    std::swap(this->name_, v.name_);
  }

private:
  friend void swap(Test& v1, Test& v2) noexcept
  {
    v1.swap(v2);
  }
};
```

### Approach #1: Straight'n'forward

```cpp
Test::Test(Test&& other) noexcept
  : handle_(std::exchange(other.handle_, nullptr))
  , name_(std::move(other.name_))
{
}

Test& Test::operator=(Test&& other) noexcept
{
  if(handle_) free(handle_);
      
  handle_ = std::exchange(other.handle_, nullptr);
  name_ = std::move(other.name_);

  return *this;
}
```

#### Pros

- The best performance

#### Cons

- Code duplication in move constructor and move assignment
- Partially the code of destructor is duplicated in the move assignment

### Approach #2: Destruction + Construction

```cpp
Test::Test(Test&& other) noexcept
  : handle_(std::exchange(other.handle_, nullptr))
  , name_(std::move(other.name_))
{
}

Test& Test::operator=(Test&& other) noexcept
{
  this->~Test();
  new (this) Test(std::move(other));

  return *this;
}
```

#### Pros

- No code duplication
- Good performance in case if there are no virtual functions

#### Cons

- Virtual Methods Table (VMT) is initialied twice (if class has virtual functions)
- Cannot be used in the base class. Base class must implement move constructor only.

### Approach #3: Copy'n'Swap

```cpp
Test::Test(Test&& other) noexcept
  : handle_(std::exchange(other.handle_, nullptr))
  , name_(std::move(other.name_))
{
}

Test& Test::operator=(Test&& other) noexcept
{
  Test (std::move(other)).swap(*this);
  return *this;
}
```

or copy and move operators 2-in-1:

```cpp
Test& Test::operator=(Test other) noexcept
{
  swap(other, *this);
  return *this;
}
```

#### Pros

- No code duplication

#### Cons

- Extra object is created
- Extra smaller objects created while swapping data members inside the `swap` function
- Some kind of code duplication in the swap function

### Approach #4: Move constructor via move-assignment

That is what you @Dongguo have found on MSDN

```cpp
Test::Test(Test&& other) noexcept
{
  *this = std::move(other);
}

Test& Test::operator=(Test&& other) noexcept
{
  if(handle_) free(handle_);
      
  handle_ = std::exchange(other.handle_, nullptr);
  name_ = std::move(other.name_);

  return *this;
}
```

#### Pros

- No code duplication

#### Cons

- Does not work for classes that contain the non-default constructible data members.
- Data members are initialized twice in the move constructor

### Links

- [[Wiki] - Move assignment operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Move_assignment_operator)
- [[cppreference.com] - Move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment)
- [[MSDN] - Move Constructors and Move Assignment Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/move-constructors-and-move-assignment-operators-cpp?view=vs-2019)
- [[Vollmann] - C++: More on Implementing Move Assignment](http://www.vollmann.ch/en/blog/implementing-move-assignment-variations-in-c++.html)
- [[Herb Sutter] - Move, simply](https://herbsutter.com/2020/02/17/move-simply/)

### More answers

- [Implementing Move Constructor by Calling Move Assignment Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118256/implementing-move-constructor-by-calling-move-assignment-operator)
- [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom/3279550#3279550)
- [Move constructor vs. Move assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59054693/move-constructor-vs-move-assignment)

Comment: All of your code has memory leaks!

Comment: @0x0 Checked all the 4 solutions. Neither has a leak. Where is it?

Comment: I think you somehow edited the code. Check out the first approach, in the move assignment, before this line, `handle_ = std::exchange(other.handle_, nullptr);` the `handle_` should be deleted because it's pointing to a temporary `Test` and you just orphan this memory by assigning it to `nullptr`.

Comment: Or simply put your code in MCVS and run any leak checker as `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`

Comment: @0x0 I did not change the code significantly. Just replaced `close_handle` with `malloc/free` (in order to test for memory leaks). The rest of code did not change. See the history of changes. I used MSVC Address Sanitizer and Visual Leak Detector. Also checked `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` - there're no leaks. The code is here [https://pastebin.com/Q6rhkLXq]